# Spark binary data source vs sc.binaryFiles

Tags: scala, apache-spark, binary-data, spark3

Spark 3.0 enables reading binary data using a new [data source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-data-sources-binaryFile.html):

```
val df = spark.read.format(“binaryFile”).load("/path/to/data")
```

Using previous spark versions you cloud load data using:

```
val rdd = sc.binaryFiles("/path/to/data")
```

Beyond having the option to access binary data using the High-Level API (`Dataset`) is there any additional benefits or features that spark 3.0 introduce with this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any additional benefit besides developers have more control over data with high level API (Dataframe/ Dataset) than low level (RDD), and they dont need to worry about performance as it is well optimized/ managed by high level API by its own.

Reference -
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/sql-data-sources-binaryFile.html

P.S. - I do think my answer does not qualify as a formal answer. I earlier wanted to add it as comment only but unable to do so because I am yet to earn privilege of commenting.. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would expect a formal documentation that discusses the differences, actual code of the new format or testing to explain this.

Comment: I find pretty confusing that you cannot control parallelism as in previous version.